# Plug-in command in Notepad++ Macro

Tags: macros, notepad++

I'd like to create a Notepad++ Macro executing the following commands:

```
1) Plugins -> Compare -> Compare.
2) View -> Word Wrap.
```

Is that possible?
Is there another workaround for the Compare-plugin breaking Word Wrap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any macros, since version 1.5.6.4 of ComparePlugin supports word wrap mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for the new version, and for updating here.
I've posted some comments:
https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/1ed3f576/#d157